# Help on a tricky MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I'd appreciate your help on this please :

I've got a table which logs when an user (id_user) where at an event (meeting, concert..) (id_event) and his score for this event (long story). Here is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE `Leaderboards` (
  `id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_event` mediumint(8) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
  `score` smallint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

Now, I'd like to suggest to an user all the users which have been to at least one event in common, and sort it by users which have been to a lot of events in common.

I might have an idea to do it in php after a row request, but is there a smarter way to do it directly through MySQL?

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: A short summary: You want a query that shows a user (lets say user_id 100) all the other users who have an event (id_event) in common?
You talk about a lot... how many is a lot? At least 3 or at least 1?

Comment: Not sure why this was down voted, I think it's a pretty good question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I might have an answer for you

```
SELECT leader1.user_id, leader2.user_id, COUNT(leader1.id) AS num
FROM       Leaderboards AS leader1
INNER JOIN Leaderboards AS leader2 ON (
    leader1.id_event = leader2.id_event AND
    leader1.user_id != leader2.user_id
)
GROUP BY leader1.user_id, leader2.user_id
ORDER BY num DESC
```

This will select the ids of the users who at least one event in common, as well as the number of events.  Finally it will order by the number of events in common (num) descending.  If you would like to do it for a specific user, add in a where clause such as below

```
WHERE leader1.user_id = :user_id
```

I also believe this query if pretty efficient as well.  Let me know if this is not quite what you need and I will see if I can make adjustments.

Comment: Thanks for the indentation Salman, I sometimes forget to do that when posting on here.

Comment: I'll try this one and see the results and perfs! I'll keep you posted, thanks for your answer!

Comment: Perfect. Nothing to say. Even with another INNER JOIN to retrieve username it's pretty fast :)

Answer (score 2):

## For user #1234

```
SELECT user_id, COUNT(1)
FROM   Leaderboards
WHERE  user_id <> 1234
AND    id_event IN (
       SELECT id_event FROM Leaderboards WHERE user_id = 1234
)
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY COUNT(1) DESC
```

Comment: this will not order by the most common event ?

Comment: Not sure if it is required. But it is as simple as adding `id_event` in the group by clause.

Comment: of course it's required  `and sort it by users which have been to a lot of events in common ` it's too easy without it

Comment: I'll happily revise my answer if OP can provide some sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following query would be a fit:

```
select count(event) as event_count, user_id from
    (select distinct id_event as event, 1 as left_userid from `Leaderboards` where user_id = 1) as leftbl,
    Leaderboards
where
    event = Leaderboards.id_event AND
    left_userid <> Leaderboards.user_id
group by
    user_id
order by
    event_count desc
```

First the subselect determines all unique events for the given user (in this case 1) and then joins this with the `Leaderboards` table. Counting the events and grouping by user does the rest.

Comment: Looks good, but I would be wary of subselects in the select part of the query, might lead to long load times.

Comment: if you have an index on user id and event id it should be fast because you hash select all events for a given user...

Answer (score 0):

I would go for the inner join one. As far as I know it causes less overhead on the server, especially when considering the number of rows in a leaderboard would be huge on a popular web application/website.